# RTSP url supported in iPhone or not

Tags: iphone, rtsp, live555

I am trying to play RTSP url in my iPhone app. I have used many Third-party API's like Live555,FFMpeg

I got code Live555 but it is not running in simulator as well as device. There is showing no error. It is always showing Build Succeeded.

Pls let me know what and how can i do in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can certainly help, but I need some more details on what you are trying to do , and the type of errors you are getting. We also have some other frameworks to try, what would help best I think is if you had a public url for whatever feed you are attempting to play.

If you like you can also compile and try it on the device using
https://github.com/mooncatventures-group

performance on device and simulator vary so much, that we just don't bother with the simulator , so everything is compiled for the device.

Comment: I am trying to play rtsp video from youtube link in iPhone
rtsp://v1.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkblQG5Hn8j0BMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp

I have download Live555 from dropcam(github) but it is not running also it is not showing error and show only Build Succeded

Comment: I am shocking there is no answer for this post. It means there is no anyone who knows RTSP play in iphone. In the other hand there are various apps available in itunes store like http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/oplayer-lite-best-free-video/id385907472?mt=8

Comment: Could you please help me with this i'm facing the same problem. i want to play youtube video using rtsp. Please contact me  comonitos@gmail.com. Thanks.

Comment: We would need more information, you can contact me if you wish I think that is in profile. I see cache3 in the url name if this is from a cache you might not be able to play it with any player. Here's a quick test , if vlc can play the video from the url, we probably can help you with a player.